# SSRS Visibility expression to hide certain Tablix, after parameter selection

Tags: reporting-services, expression, visibility

Hi All I have a ssrs report with 6 tablix and all 6 using the same dataset1, but with tablix filtering for 6 unique service provider, one for each tablix.

The user selects a country from the parameter. And based on which country the user selected: Out of the 6 service provider, some of them may not be available in that country and will display a blank tablix table with only the column headers.

What I want: Is there a way to change the visibility settings so that whichever service provider tablix is empty, they would become invisible?

For example: User selects Canada:

Provider1: Available in Canada, Show Tablix

Provider2: Available in Canada, Show Tablix

Provider3: Not available in Canada results in blank tablix - *Turn visibility to hide*

Provider4: Not available in Canada results in blank tablix - *Turn visibility to hide*

Provider5: Available in Canada, Show Tablix

Provider6: Not available in Canada results in blank tablix - *Turn visibility to hide*

So only Tablixs for Provider 1, 2, and 5 will show on the report.

I am assuming this will use the IIF expression? I just need some guidance on what would be the best way to accomplish this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a similar expression to set `Hidden` property of a `Tablix`:

```
=IIf(CountRows("YourTablixName") = 0, True, False)
```

Comment: You can also refer to parameters in the expression, with the syntax `Parameters!Country.Value`.

Comment: ok but in this case I don't think is a good solution using parameters. You already have a dataset which contains data or not: if a dataset is empty don't display tablix.

Comment: Thank you so much! Did not even knew this expression existed. I have a text box associated with each tablix to display which service provider which tablix is representing. Is there a way to apply the same visibility settings? I tried using the same expression you posted but it threw an error stating " 'Textbox83’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."

Comment: Correct, only one dataset. I changed from "tablix" to "dataset" for the textbox expression and it is still throwing the same score parameter error.

Comment: @tezzo Thank you!! Really appreciate your help on this

Comment: @tezzo your answer works perfectly for the tablix. Its only the textbox that are having the scope issue. I am using "=IIF(CountRows("Tablix1") = 0, True, False)" for the tablix visibility expression and it works perfectly.

Comment: ok, perfect! never used this expression with object name. ;)

why don't you put Textbox inside Tablix structure, "playing" with empty header/column to obtain the desired graphic output?

Comment: @tezzo that is a brilliant work around. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The **NoRowsMessage** property of a Tablix may be useful to your needs. If the filters result in the tablix having no data to use, this will show a message instead of displaying the column/row headers. This can be static or an expression:

```
="No Provider3 data available for " & Parameters!Country.Value
```

The `Font` properties of a tablix (rather than the properties of it's cells) control how the No Rows Message displays.